# How to ping behind a Proxy on Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, ping

I found this working solution for Linux. https://askubuntu.com/questions/428408/can-not-ping-google-using-proxy/428414 .
Any suggestion for Windows? I tried:

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
ping google.com    # works, proxy set for this bash session.
```

but it does not work (it still says: "Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ping with proxy authentication in windows](http://superuser.com/questions/739979/ping-with-proxy-authentication-in-windows)